# JavaScript- Including loop variable into HTML value='' " property

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a drop-down for a "minutes" field using a `for` loop. I am able to display the values into the drop-down. What I am not able to do is including the `value=" "` property to the drop-down. My `value` is the the same as the number I am creating with the `for` loop.

```
<select id="autoDropDown">
        <script>
            var minute=0;
            for (var i=0; i <=58; i++)
            {
                minute++;
                document.write("<option value=\"minute\">" + minute + "</option>");

            }

        </script>
    </select>
```

So, How do I get the `value` property included by the `for` loop. AND i also want to "get" the selected value and display it with `alert()` in JavaScript.

Comment: The same way you're adding the text, string concatenation. JS doesn't know that `minute` is a variable even if your escape.

Comment: you are not doing the string concatenation `document.write("<option value=\"" + minute + "\">" + minute + "</option>");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as "Chris G" with little modification

```
<select id="autoDropDown">
    <script>
        for (var i=0; i <60; i++)
        {
            document.write("<option value='"+ i +"'>" + ("0" + i).slice(-2) + "</option>");
        }
    </script>
</select>
<button onclick="alert(parseInt(document.getElementById('autoDropDown').value));"> Get Value </button>
<button onclick="alert(Number(document.getElementById('autoDropDown').value));"> Get Value </button>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <select id="autoDropDown">
        <script>
            var minute=0;
            for (var i=0; i <=58; i++)
            {
                minute++;
                document.write("<option value=\""+minute+"\">" + minute + "</option>");

            }

        </script>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine single and double quotes. Just use single quotes inside the string:

```
"<option value='" + minute + "' >" + minute + "</option>"
```

And why would you use a secondary variable?

```
<select id="autoDropDown">
    <script>
        for (var i = 1; i <= 59; i++)
        {
            document.write("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
        }
    </script>
</select>
```

As for getting it:

```
var minute = Number(document.getElementById('autoDropDown').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onchange method to get the value, something like this:

```
<select id="autoDropDown" onchange="someFunction()">
```

or

```
<select id="autoDropDown" onchange="alert(this.value)">
```

to get te value every time yoy choose a diferent value.

for setting the value:

```
document.write("<option value="+ minute +">" + minute + "</option>");
```